# Direct to specific part of page on load in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a community page name 'global-device' which has a LWC component and it has a child LWC.

parentLWC.html

```
<template>
....
<!--parent html code-->
  <div id="messagenotif">
    <a name="notifpage"></a>
    <template if:true={showChild}>
      <c-child-lwc para1={para1value}></c-child-lwc>
     </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

Now, when I land on this page, URL looks like this:
`s/global-device?linkId=5&mypageid=5003M000001fMQHQA2#notifpage`

I am using `#notifpage` to direct to `notifpage` section of the page when the page loads. Page gets loaded as expected but does not get directed to this section.

In the `connectedcallback` method of `parentLWC`, I am making a server call to set value of `showchild` and `para1value`, but I think this should not have any affect on the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Phil, I am now using `renderedCallback` method to check if the URL has fragment identifier `#notifpage` and then move to that section using `scrollIntoView`.

`ParentLWC.html`

```
<template>
....
<!--parent html code-->
  <div class="notifpage">
    <template if:true={showChild}>
      <c-child-lwc para1={para1value}></c-child-lwc>
     </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

'parentLWC.js'

```
renderedCallback(){
  if(location.href.includes('#notifpage') ){
    var elmnt = this.template.querySelector('.notifpage');
    elmnt.scrollIntoView();
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

LWCs load and render asynchronously, yet the # fragment identifier is applied at the time the page is loaded. Thus the named anchor with the fragment identifier you have used doesn't exist at the appropriate time and the browser cannot scroll to it.

You would need to have code that waits for the page's loading (including the LWC rendering) to complete and then apply some code that finds and "scrolls to" the named element.

Comment: Should I try with renderedCallback method?

Comment: You could build the behaviour into the LWC itself in the renderedCallback, as you said, where (if the URL includes its fragment identifier) the LWC would simply ask the browser to scroll to its named anchor.